# using redux-persist, how do you return only part of an object as part of the default state

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-persist

The project I took over is using redux-persist to set initial state.  However, I only want part of the initial state to be changed.

```
export let defaultState = {
    devices: {},
    canBeDeleted: false,
    willBeDeleted: null,

};
```

I only want devices to be updated when redux-persist rehydrates.

```
export default function (state = defaultState, action) {
    if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
        let incoming = action.payload.device;
        console.log('checking actin.payload.device: ', action.payload.device);
        if (incoming) {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload.device.devices
            }
        }
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }
```

This resulted in nothing being returned.  How do I specify that I only want the array of devices to be returned, while the rest of the default state gets load?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
        // console.log('REHYDRATE: action.payload.device.devices: ', action.payload.device.devices)
        let incoming = action.payload.device;
        if (incoming) {
            return {
                ...state,
                devices: action.payload.device.devices
            }
        }
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }
```